# react query is not working cache. althogh i add option staleTime: Infinity

Tags: caching, react-query

i try react query. but, it is not working cache..

i tried this :

```
const getTags = async (): Promise<tagRes> => {
  const jwtToken = getJWTToken("token");
  if (jwtToken) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
      },
    };

    const { data } = await instance.get("/api/user/myhashtags", config);
    return data;
  } else {
    const { data } = await instance.get("/api/user/myhashtags");
    return data;
  }
};


useQuery<tagRes, Error | void>("getTag", getTags, { staleTime: Infinity });
```

when i reload or go back to other page. i expect it call once.
However, whenever i reload or comeback, always call api

Why is React Query not using the cache? Am i doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: What does "refresh" mean? Do you mean a page reload, because react-query caches in memory only.

Comment: @TkDodo wow,,, i realize react query is in memory. and i found some article. i read "https://codemachine.dev/things-i-learned-while-using-react-query-part-1 " good article,, i learn more react query.

Comment: @TkDodo i have one more question.. 

i call api :
export const FetchTagListQuery = () => {
  return useQuery<tagRes, Error | void>("getTag", getTags, { staleTime: 10000 });
};

the "FetchTagListQuery" function is called two component. 
example - 
1. EditMyInfoContainer 
2. TabContainer
===
i give stale time 10000 in FetchTagListQuery. but 
EditMyInfoContainer and TabContainer call api.